# Remove duplicate values in csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file wit values like

```
68,68
70,70
80,90
```

Here i would like it to remove the duplicates i.e. give the output

```
68
70
80,90
```

Or

```
 68,
 70,
 80,90
```

But i tried searching everywhere and was not able to find how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your input, a naive approach could be fine:

```
$ cat test 
68,68
70,70
80,90
$ cat readvals.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
import csv
vals = [] # a list for the entire file
with open('test') as infile:
    lines = csv.reader(infile,delimiter=',')
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        vals.append([]) # append a sub-list for this row.
        for val in line:
            if val not in vals[i]:
                vals[i].append(val) # add values for the row
print(vals)
$ python readvals.py
[['68'], ['70'], ['80', '90']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing duplicate rows I use this code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

df.to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I need it, thank you Rafia Manzoor and Sushanth

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to have a look at these below since its not clear about your requirement.

pandas documentation:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Example ref: https://www.journaldev.com/33488/pandas-drop-duplicate-rows-drop_duplicates-function